# Converting xlsx to csv with pattern matching in Python not working

Tags: csv, xlsx, python-3.9

I have several `xlsx` files in directory. But i want to search `xlsx` file with filename `20230406115500.001.A0.XZI.INVOICING_ES101_Anlage_DISCO_Split_20230405_114751.xlsx`.

I wanted to search above file with pattern matching something like `*ES101*.xlsx` and then convert this `xlsx` file into `csv`. There is only one file with this file name pattern. I am trying below python code:

```
import pandas as pd

read_file = pd.read_excel (r'/home/repo/"*ES101*.xlsx"')')
read_file.to_csv (r'/home/repo/ES101.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

But it throws error `No such file or directory`. I am running this python code in Linux server. I am using `Python3.9` version.

Comment: There is only one file with this name? you want to read all the files containing that name and merge it in the same dataframe?

Comment: there is only one file actually with the search pattern *ES101*.xlsx in the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just search with the glob function and then read the file:

```
from glob import glob

# it searches all the files containing the pattern, in this case I take the first and only one
file_name = glob('/home/repo/*ES101*.xlsx')[0]

dataframe = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='sheet_name')
dataframe.to_csv("file_name.csv", index=False)

# if you want the same name for the file you just can
dataframe.to_csv(file_name.split('.')[0]+'.csv', index=False)
```

You need to have the xlsxwriter engine installed.

Comment: thanks i will try but if i just use pandas and if i want to search file pattern then how i provide ?

Comment: df = pd.read_excel('ES101.xlsx', header=0) #,   in this command how can i provide pattern to look for that specific file ?

Comment: The read excel function doesn't have a pattern matching function included. You need to make the regex search before using this function. Here you have the definition of the first input in the read_excel method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Just call: pd.read_excel(glob('/home/repo/*ES101*.xlsx')[0], index=False, sheet_name='sheet_name', engine='xlsxwriter') or iterate and merge all the posible matching paths.

Comment: its throwing error TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index' and where did you provide csv filename ?

Comment: Sorry I did it from what I recalled I just updated the answer

Comment: now it says No such file or directory..looks like file pattern not working

Comment: The absolute path to the file is correct? If the file is in the same path where the python script is running you can just do: glob('*ES101*.xlsx')[0] . Make sure the absolute path is correct and make sure that your user has read privileges to the folder containing the xlsx file.

Comment: Yes i am in the same directory and also it has read and write permission ..i tried with glob('ES101.xlsx')[0] but still it throws same error ..dont i need to use * for file pattern ?

Comment: You cant do glob('ES101.xlsx')[0] you need the * for pattern matching like the answer i gave ;) glob('*ES101*.xlsx')[0] then print if the glob function is finding something. It should return the file you want.

Comment: yes i also tried now with * for pattern matching but still same error

Comment: Can you execute:
from os import popen
print(popen("ls -l").read())

And share the printed output?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 odi odi 13580429 Apr  6 12:05 20230406115500.001.A0.XZI.INVOICING_ES101_Anlage_DISCO_Split_20230405_114751.xlsx
drwxr-xr-x 2 odi odi        0 May 25 17:09 archive
-rwxr-xr-x 1 odi odi 27028252 Apr  6 12:38 ES102.csv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 odi odi 80561287 Apr  6 12:27 ES103.csv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 odi odi 11045062 Apr  6 12:05 ES301_ES302_ES313.csv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 odi odi  9841990 Apr  6 12:38 ES410.csv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 odi odi  9841988 Apr  6 12:38 IS410.csv
-rwxr-xr-x 1 odi odi      321 May 26 12:16 test.py

Comment: And can you share the output of: from os import getcwd print(getcwd())

Comment: yes its /home/repo

Comment: And the glob function is finding the file I gess? you get a list containing the file you want to read right?

Comment: i think glob function not finding the file thats why it throws error

Comment: file_name = glob("*ES101*.xlsx")[0]
print (file_name) i did this and it prints the output as ES101.xlsx so it means its find the file

Comment: can we move the char to discussion i think the issue is with dataframe not recognising ES101.xlsx file

Comment: Yes should be moved to disscussion

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253838/converting-xlsx-to-csv  you can join here please